# Push notification in Android fails with "connectivity details to GCM are not set"

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst

We are running MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 and are using both iOS Push as well as Android Push messages. We have an issue with talking to GCM after a server restart.

MFP is installed on a WebSphere AppServer Network Deployment version 8.5.5 environment. This server is running behind a corporate firewall.

We set the environment entries to specify the proxy-server MFP should use to talk to GCM; as documented here: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html

After a full restart of WAS, meaning a stop of the App Servers, the Node Agents and the Deployment Manager and a subsequent start in opposite order - GCM push works fine.

However, if we restart just the App Server MFP is running on, the following errors appear in the server log:

```
[10/28/15 11:04:17:022 CET] 00000123 JavaScriptInt I com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation info Wed Oct 28 2015 11:04:17 GMT+0100 (CET): Send MyIT Broadcast message for IT Failure with title 'Test Push Message 3' [project babel]
[10/28/15 11:04:17:061 CET] 00000156 GCMMediator   E com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator sendOrWait FPWSE1051E: Notification through Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) was not sent to application 'MyITHelpdeskApp-android-0.1.2' because connectivity details to GCM are not set.
```

And push message sent to Android devices fail to be delivered. It seems environment entries for web modules are not loaded correctly upon AppServer restart, or MFP does not pick-up namespace entries correctly when reloaded.

Is there any setting we missed? Or is there a way to force the update of the namespace with the corresponding GCM Proxy settings?

Comment: What is it not able to pick specifically, just the proxy settings or any JNDI property?

Comment: Idan, we only know about the GCM settings - there are some other environment/JNDI settings e.g. `ibm.worklight.topology.platform` which are still presumably being picked up correctly because the server is otherwise still working.

Comment: Lennert, it might be worth trying to turn on `Naming=all` trace for WAS (which would then appear in `trace.log`) to see if the GCM JNDI properties are being found at all. See here for more info: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21143296#show-hide

Comment: Just to update the status of this: we have enabled `Naming=all` tracing and we see the GCM proxy JNDI properties set as expected. Still a mystery what the phrase "connectivity details to GCM are not set" means.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Have you managed to make any progress here?

Comment: @IdanAdar yes, just wrote up an answer. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the answer in this case was that the `.wlapp` deployed to the server was an old version, without an appropriate GCM connection key (in other words, it was a development issue, not an infrastructural one). On fixing this, GCM starting working.